# Why do I get a #1064 with INSERT INTO VALUES?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sql-insert

I created the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE contactos (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre VARCHAR(60), 
  email VARCHAR(60), 
  password VARCHAR(60), 
  fecha TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  KEY(id)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

But when I try to insert values into the table I get error #1064:

```
INSERT INTO contactos('ID', 'nombre', 'email', 'password', 'fecha') VALUES (NULL, 'Armando', 'armando_zax@hotmail.com', 'hola', NOW() );
```

I have researched a lot, but couldn´t get what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Also: [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and back ticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11321491/1941241)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Becouse you are use a wrong quotes
"INSERT INTO contactos(`ID`, `nombre`, `email`, `password`, `fecha`) VALUES ..."
When you are mean a field name - then you should use ` quote. When a string constant - use ' quote.

Comment: A `\`` is not a quote character. It is a back tick or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent, vs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark

Comment: May be, but 'Dear myself' call it as an `quote`  ))) Sorry, i'm russian )

Comment: Thank you so much! This code line worked for me:   INSERT INTO `contactos`(`ID`, `nombre`, `email`, `password`, `fecha`) VALUES (NULL, 'Armando', 'armando_zax@hotmail.com', 'hola', NOW())